# How to Delete Clone sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-clone

My Query is to delete the clone sandbox, how could I do that although I have all the admin permission.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317750&type=1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for sometime to delete if you have recently created it.

It should follow the Sandbox refresh intervals depending on what type of sandbox you cloned :

- Developer Sandbox: 1 day
- Developer Pro Sandbox: 1 day
- Partial Data Sandbox: 5 days
- Full Copy Sandbox: 29 days

e.g. 1 day means wait 1 day after you cloned then only you are allowed to delete or refresh

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317750&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a sandbox will completely delete your sandbox and all its contents. A sandbox can only be deleted if it's refresh interval has passed. If you do not see the delete option, you will need to wait until the refresh interval has passed in order to delete the sandbox.

Refer the help article [Delete a sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317750&type=1)